# using ASP.NET to display the visitor location like country, state and city in master page

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

How to  get visitor location like country, state and city  using ASP.NET, i saw some examples All are based on IP Address to get the Details(based on some free services), now my problem is above example that services only working registered Ip addresses, but now my task is when user browse the my asp.net website, display the Country, state and city how it possible, please give me any suggestion, urgent

Thank u
hemanth

Comment: You're aware of the fact that this isn't really reliable, right?

Comment: hmm, i think use lan ip to get the details,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a WebClient request to something like ipinfodb, if you [register](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php) (free) for an api key:

```
var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
var ip = Request.UserHostAddress;
var url = string.Format("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key={0}&ip={1}", apiKey, ip);
var info = client.DownloadString(url).ToString();
```

Then parse and display the `info` in your page.

There are many IP locator APIs, whichever one you use, the general idea is the same, but you will parse the `info` result differently depending on the service.

But walther is correct, getting location info from IP addresses isn't always reliable.

Comment: i executed above code ip address is 127.0.0.1 and no results found, and i could run  application using iis get my pc ip address like 10.51.51.121 and no results found , waht is the problem

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is localhost - it has no location information associated with it, every computer is 127.0.0.1 to itself.  If you have a real IP address like 10.51.51.121 that doesn't resolve to a location, that's just part of the unreliability of translating IPs to physical locations.

Answer (score 0):

here my solution in asp.net c#

```
    public async void MakeUserLoginHistoryAsync()
    {
        #region Get data from ip2location
        var ip = "43.240.503.78";
        string apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var url = string.Format("https://api.ip2location.io/?key={0}&ip={1}", apiKey, ip);
        var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
        Console.WriteLine($"{response}");
        #endregion
    }
```

- here ip will be your public ip
  *apiKey you need to get from their official website https://www.ip2location.io/

[image]